# Finding letters in a string returns different number

Tags: c++

Why does `phrase.find("333", 0)` return `4`, and `phrase.find("333", 2)` return `4` as well?

Is my program working correctly? Is it not supposed to search for 333 after second character?

```
int main() {
    string phrase = "text333 fdsfwsawa";
  
    cout << phrase.find("333", 2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find ?

Comment: The result is not the distance from the starting point. If `k` is less than the string's length and `ch` is found after `k`, then `s[s.find(ch,k)] == ch`.

Comment: Hint: What is `phrase.find("333", 12)`?

Comment: What did you expect them to return?

Comment: I expected it to count from x since it's second. And the answer I expected should be 2

Answer (score 0):

**size_type find( const basic_string& str, size_type pos = 0 ) const;**

Above we have a declaration of Find().

Return value:
size_type : Position of the first character of the found substring or npos if no such substring is found.

Parameter:
str: your input string

pos: position from which you want to start search in string, default is 0

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
 
void print(std::string::size_type n, std::string const &s)
{
    if (n == std::string::npos) {
        std::cout << "not found\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "found: " << s.substr(n) << '\n';
    }
}
 
int main()
{
    std::string::size_type n;
    std::string const s = "This is a string";
 
    // search from beginning of string
    std::cout<< s.find("is");
 
    // search from position 5
    std::cout<< s.find("is", 5);
    
    // find a single character
    std::cout<< s.find('a');
   
}
```

output:

```
2
5
8
```

In your question `phrase.find("333", 0)` it will start the search from position zero and it finds "333" at position 4.